# Loop that return AND value in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, loops, solr

I have created this loop in MVC:

```
//this identify my user
string tmpUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

//this find user in database and compare his username with Identity name and returns userID
using (var dbUs = new userDbEntities())
{
   var whoisloged = (from user in dbUs.UsersTables
   where user.username == tmpUser
   select user.userID).FirstOrDefault(); 

   //get all destinations for user userid
   var list1 = dbUs.CustomerTables.Where(m => m.UserId == whoisloged).Select(m => m.Customer);

   var list2 = dbUs.CustomTypes.Where(m => list1.Contains(m.Id_NewCustomerType)).Select(m => m.CustomerType);

   //this is LOOP that must return my values
   foreach (var customer in list2)
   {
      string test = customer;
      return new SolrQuery(test);
   }
```

Now Problem is in my LOOP foreach... Why is returning only first value? no matter that I have more data in the database.

My result sholud be something like this:

e.g. user Somebody login in app. He/She have in database saved his/her roles (CustomerTable in code) that are e.g. A, B and C, so loop should return me something like this:

```
return new SolrQuery(A) + return new SolrQuery(B) + return new SolrQuery(C); // + is refer as AND
```

Realy thanks for help and any ideas...

Comment: I see that I do not need "string test = customer", I put in return new SoleQuery(customer), but result is the same, it returns only one result...

Comment: But without return sentence ... foreach returns me correct all values.

Comment: can you show definition of ``SolrQuery(test)``?

Comment: what do you mean by definition. SolrQuery is from library SolrNet that you can import with Packet Manager: install packages solrnet

Comment: SolrQuery() definition is: SolrQuery.SolrQuery(string query) Constructor if that you mean

Comment: It returns string values... e.g. "CTTW", "JADA", "LUKA", etc...

Answer (score 1):

The first return leaves not only the foreach, but the whole function (as return is intended to do). If you want to do more than one query in the loop, you have to collect the results and return them afterwards...

```
string result ="";
foreach (var customer in list2)
{
  result = result + new SolrQuery(customer);
}
return result;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It underline me second result in sentence result = result + ... and says: Local variable 'result' might not be initialized before accessing ... what that mean...

Comment: Then initialize it (see above in my sample).

Comment: Ok, helps, but now underline last result in return result with this error: Cannot convert expression type 'string' to return type 'SolrNet.ISolrQuery'... realy thanks you for helping me, your idea seems useful, so I mark your answer as useful

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that:-

```
return new SolrQuery(test);
```

returns a single `SolrQuery` and then *exits the function* breaking out of your loop.

What you probably want to do is modify your method signature:-

```
public SolrQuery MyMethod(...)
```

to:-

```
public IEnumerable<SolrQuery> MyMethod(...)
```

to indicate that you want the method to return a *sequence* of items, rather than a single one.

Then you can use the [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) keyword to create the sequence:-

```
foreach (var customer in list2)
{
   yield return new SolrQuery(customer);
}
```

---

Or, better, you can just return the result of your LINQ query (which is already a sequence). Replace:-

```
var list2 = dbUs.CustomTypes.Where(m => list1.Contains(m.Id_NewCustomerType))
                            .Select(m => m.CustomerType);
```

with:-

```
return dbUs.CustomTypes.Where(x => list1.Contains(x.Id_NewCustomerType))
                       .Select(x => new SolrQuery(x.CustomerType))
                       .ToList();
```

and then remove everything after.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it:

```
            List<string> result = new List<string>();

            foreach (var customer in seznam2)
            {
                result.Add(customer);
            }

            SolrQueryInList queryInList = new SolrQueryInList("destination", result);

            return queryInList;
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be better just doing `new SolrQueryInList("destination", seznam2);` rather than dumping everything from one list into another?